# Why is this simple bash script throwing an error on if/then/else?

Tags: bash, shell

If I try to run this script:

```
clear
echo -n "please enter a value"

read num 

if [ "$num" -eq 8 ] then
        echo "you entered 8"
else
        echo "the number you entered was not 8"
```

I get the following output/error:

> please enter a value5
>   ./script.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
>   ./script.sh: line 9: else'

Why wont this script run?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a semicolon or newline after the `if` clause, and there's no `fi` atthe end of the `if` block.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo -n "please enter a value"

read num 

if [ "$num" -eq 8 ]
then
        echo "you entered 8"
else
        echo "the number you entered was not 8"
fi
```

Some other suggestions:

- Scripts should always start with a `#!` line to tell the system which 
  interpreter to use
- Your comparison `[ "$num" -eq 8 ]` is a numeric comparison. If you're not sure that the user will actually enter a number, consider using a string comparison instead, `[ 8 = "$num" ]`
- You can wrap the prompt into the `read` statement, `read -p "Please enter a value: " num`

Comment: @user4668401 All `bash` interpreters follow the same syntax. You can either do `if condition; then` on a single line, or `if condition` `then` on two separate lines. Some people prefer the single line approach; I prefer two.

Comment: thanks, after re-reading your answer - I realised what you meant with:  "You're missing a semicolon **or newline** after the if clause" , thanks very helpful!